# sscanf unknown error?

Tags: c++, file, input, formatting

My input file has many lines similar to :

```
ATOM 339 OP1 DG D 218 72.270 54.958 23.040 1.00 27.52 O
```

I want to extract the 3 coordinates:  `72.270  54.958  23.040` from every line.
I have stored every line as a string and use the following to extract coordinates:

```
sscanf(protein[j].c_str(),"%s %s %s %s %s %s %f %f %f",useless1,useless2,useless3,useless4,useless5,useless6,&xCord,&yCord,&zCord);
```

Here useless are all names of strings.
This gives **many** warnings and program crashes:

```
warning: format '%s' expects type 'char*', but argument 6 has type 'int'.          
warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type 'struct std::string' through '...'; call will abort at runtime.
```

What is the problem?

Also will sscanf() crash if its input char array has multiple spaces instead of just one? (to remove possibility of this error, i removed multiple spaces in input file.)

**EDIT:
I had checked this possibility of them being ints first. (I am not this big a noob.) This is the initial code:**

```
string str,useless1,useless2,useless3,useless4,useless5,useless6,useless7,useless8,useless9;
```

Comment: Sscanf is a horrible way to parse anything. Its use should be banned by the Geneva convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the problem?

The compiler ***just told you*** what it is.

> format `'%s'` expects type `'char *'`, but argument 6 has type `'int'`.

So the 6th format specifier in the string tells `scanf()` to expect a `char *`, but you pass an `int` instead.

> cannot pass objects of non-POD type `'struct std::string'` through `'...'`

This means that C++ objects (more precisely, variables that are not plain old data types) cannot be passed to a variadic function. And you're trying to do that. And it even warns you it **will break.**

---

Other comments:

1. In C++, it's seldom advisable to use C functions. You should generally stick with `std::cin` et al. for better style.
2. However, if you, despite all the above, insist to use C functions, ***leave poor `scanf()` alone.*** It doesn't do what you think it does anyway. Get a line of user input using `fgets()`, and parse it using either `std::stringstream` or with the help of some of the `<cstring>` or `<string.h>` functions.

Comment: +1 for being humane about `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that argument six which is `useless6` is an int not a `char *`.

This reference explains why you can not pass [Non-POD to variadic functions](http://tycho.ws/blog/2010/06/variadic)